# Помогите разобраться с выборкой данных из связанных таблиц MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Вопрос простой, но не могу даже сообразить как это погуглить. Есть две связанных таблицы, одна справочник кошельков (альфа карта, карта сбера и т.д.), вторая таблица операций перемещения денег, из ID первого кошелька в ID второго.
На фото видно, что `PHPMyAdmin` видит описание взятое из связанной таблицы, а с названием кошелька:

[image: Фото]

Но как получить его в запросе я что-то не соображу.

Сейчас у меня такой запрос, но он выводит только ID кошельков, а не их названия:

```
     SELECT 
            movements.id AS move_id,
            DATE_FORMAT(movements.date, '%d %M %Y') AS show_date,
            movements.wallet_from AS wallet_from,
            movements.wallet_to AS wallet_to,
            movements.value AS value,
            wallets.description AS wallet_name
        FROM `movements`
        JOIN wallets on movements.wallet_from = wallets.id
        WHERE movements.date >= '{$_SESSION['calendar_of_move_from']}' AND movements.date <= '{$_SESSION['calendar_of_move_to']}'
            ORDER BY movements.date;");
```

- https://russiahomefinance.000webhostapp.com/images/2.JPG - общий вид таблиц со связями
- https://russiahomefinance.000webhostapp.com/images/3.JPG - так выглядит содержимой справочной таблицы с кошельками.

Comment: как результат смотрите? в wallet_name должен название кошелька вернуть. Пробовали отдельно запрос выполнить и резльутат проверить? Может в php просто неправильно данные обрабатываете? если все-таки в mysql косяк, то будет лучше, если воспроизведете ошибку на http://sqlfiddle.com/ - там можно будет потрогать и исправить запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот запрос, выводящий еще названия кошельков:

```
     SELECT 
            movements.id AS move_id,
            DATE_FORMAT(movements.date, '%d %M %Y') AS show_date,
            movements.wallet_from AS wallet_from,
            movements.wallet_to AS wallet_to,
            movements.value AS value,
            w_from.description AS wallet_from_name,
            w_to.description AS wallet_to_name
        FROM `movements`
        JOIN wallets w_from on movements.wallet_from = w_from.id
        JOIN wallets w_to on movements.wallet_to = w_to.id
        WHERE movements.date >= '{$_SESSION['calendar_of_move_from']}' AND movements.date <= '{$_SESSION['calendar_of_move_to']}'
            ORDER BY movements.date;");
```

Comment: ЧЕЛ СПАСИБО!!!! ВСЮ ГОЛОВУ СЛОМАЛ СЕГОДНЯ СЕБЕ!!! 
        JOIN wallets w_from on movements.wallet_from = w_from.id
        JOIN wallets w_to on movements.wallet_to = w_to.id
вот эти две строчки были решением моей проблемы, я не знал как два раза join к одной и той же таблице сделать, алиасы и потом к ним обращение, проверил, работает, супер, спасибо ещё раз!!!